# How do i check the specific items in different collections exist by POST method in SpringBoot rest api

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

In my program I have three classes and for each one, I have three collections in the same db
The Player Class:

```
 package thesisMongoProject;

    import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;    
    import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

    @Document(collection = "player")
    public class Player {
        @Id
        @NotBlank
        private String nickname;
        @NotBlank
        private String firstname;
        @NotBlank
        private String lastname;
        @NotBlank
        private String email;

        public Player(String nickname, String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
            super();
            this.nickname = nickname;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getNickname() {
            return nickname;
        }
        public void setNickname(String nickname) {
            this.nickname = nickname;
        }
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }
        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }
        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Player [nickname=" + nickname + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email="
                    + email + "]";
        }


    }
```

The Game Class:

```
        package thesisMongoProject;

    import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;    
    import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;


    @Document(collection = "game")
    public class Games {
        @Id
        @NotBlank
        private String code;
        @NotBlank
        private String title;
        @NotBlank
        private String software_house;
        @NotBlank
        private String version;
        @NotBlank
        private String release_year;
        public Games(@NotBlank String code, @NotBlank String title, @NotBlank String software_house,
                @NotBlank String version, @NotBlank @NotBlank @NotBlank String release_year) {
            super();
            this.code = code;
            this.title = title;
            this.software_house = software_house;
            this.version = version;
            this.release_year = release_year;
        }
        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }
        public void setCode(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        public String getSoftware_house() {
            return software_house;
        }
        public void setSoftware_house(String software_house) {
            this.software_house = software_house;
        }
        public String getVersion() {
            return version;
        }
        public void setVersion(String version) {
            this.version = version;
        }
        public @NotBlank String getRelease_year() {
            return release_year;
        }
        public void setRelease_year(@NotBlank String release_year) {
            this.release_year = release_year;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Games [code=" + code + ", title=" + title + ", software_house=" + software_house + ", version="
                    + version + ", release_year=" + release_year + "]";
        }


    }
```

And the Score Class:

```
 package thesisMongoProject;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;

@Document(collection = "score")
public class Score {
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String score;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String player;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String code;
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Date date;
    private List<History> history = null;



    public Score(@NotBlank String score, String player, String code, List<History> history, Date date) {
        super();
        this.score = score;
        this.player = player;
        this.code = code;
        this.history = history;
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
    public String getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
    public void setPlayer(String player) {
        this.player = player;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public List<History> getHistory() {
        return history;
    }
    public void setHistory(List<History> history) {
        this.history = history;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Score [score=" + score + ", player=" + player + ", code=" + code + ", history=" + history + ", date="
                + date + "]";
    }

}
```

The View Class:

```
 package thesisMongoProject;

public class Views {
    public static class Creat{}

}
```

The POST method:

```
//Create Score
        @PostMapping
        public ResponseEntity<?> createScore(@RequestBody @JsonView(Views.class) @Valid  Score score) {
            //check player exist
            Player p = prepo.findByNickname(score.getPlayer());
            //check game's cod exist
            Games g = grepo.findByCode(score.getCode());
            //check score exist
            Score s = srepo.findByScore(score.getScore());
            if(s != null)
            {
                return ResponseEntity.status(409).body("Conflict!!");
            }
            else if((p != null) || (g != null)) {
                srepo.save(score);
                return ResponseEntity.status(201).body("Created!"); 
            }
            else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(400).body("Bad Request!");
            }

        }
```

In fact, in POST method, The body of POST requests only contains player, game, score, date and not history, and for this issue i used @JSONView(Views.class) annotation. When a POST request is issued, the service “score” should check whether the specified “player” and “game” do exist (i.e., whether there exist both a player with that nickname and a game with that code); otherwise, 400 Bad Request.
At the first I used @DBRef for player and code such as,
@DBRef String player
@DBRef String code
inside Score class, and i used 
Public Score findByPlayerAndCode(String player, String code); 
inside my ScoreRepository for checking player and game;s code exist or not, but i had an error. Then I used instances of PlayerRepository and GameRepository for doing that, but Nothing Change for me and my program still does not work.
could you help me what I must do, please

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: In fact, I had different Error. for now the Error is "HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.util.Date'. Check configuration for 'date'".

Comment: In Postman i did: {
    "score": "340",
    "player": "sabaa",
    "code": "w12",
    "date": "2020-05-14"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Class Score you have used annotation `@NotBlank` with type date. Which is wrong, `@NotBlank` can be used only with String.

Use `@NotNull` with Date type.

```java
    @NotNull
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Date date;
```

Reference - https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank

Comment: Yes it is correct, I forgot to correct this but still i have an error 500 Internal Server Error...No message available. I

Comment: I wrote above. the error is: 500 Internal Server Error  message: No message available

Comment: check console on your IDE - eclipse/intelliJ .. you would have received error

Comment: oh sorry i made mistake. when i run my program in consol i do not have any error. but when i use POST method in Postman  i have that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213223/discussion-between-hemant-and-user8903246).

Comment: You can accept answer if it solved your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers